# Representation/Character theory of $S_3$: What is the Vector space $V$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

This is a basic question that I may have a misunderstanding on.

When we study the character table of a group, say $S_3$, what vector space are we looking at?

I understand that a linear representation of a group $G$ in a vector space $V$ is a homomorphism $\rho:G\to GL(V)$.

In this case, are we allowed to choose the vector space $V$? I know that all finite dimensional vector spaces are isomorphic, hence choosing the dimension of the vector space suffices.

Do we choose $\dim (V)=|G|$ the order of the group $G$?

Thanks for clearing my doubts.

Comment: You probably want to write $S_3$, lest people think you're asking about the group of unit quaternions, identified with the 3-dimensional sphere.

Comment: I don't understand your question : by definition, the character table of $G$ is about all irreducible representations of $G$, so it involves several vector spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When we study the character table of a group, say $S_3$, what vector space are we looking at?

When we are studying character table, we are not looking at **a vector space**.. We are looking at a collection of vector spaces..

Dimension of each of these vector spaces is related to the order of the group (in the case of finite groups)..

To each irreducible representation we have a vector space associated with it. Suppose $V_i$ is vector space related to irreducible representation $\eta_i$ for $1\leq i\leq r$ we then have

$$|G|=n_1^2+n_2^2+\cdots+n_r^2$$
where $n_i$ is the dimension of vector space $V_i$..